# Spring, Form tag based Datepicker in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

Actually in my Spring application i'm using spring based `form` tag in my jsp code.

And add the functionality for this `<form:input>`,provide DatePicker using Jquery.

And here is my Jsp code..

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/custom.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <form:form action="form/form1"
        modelAttribute="form1">
               <label class="control_label_c">From : </label>
          <div class="controls_c">
              <form:input type="text" path="fromDate" class="date-picker" />
        </div>
    </form:form>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But date picker not working (not visible)...

Is there any problem in this spring based form tag? or

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Have you tried with pure html code like `<input type="text" name="fromDate" class="date-picker" />`?

Comment: yes i'm trying.. there also not working..

Comment: Datepicker without initialize any options - `$('.date-picker').datepicker();`?

Comment: no .. this is also i'm trying.. with <input..> html tag working but <form:input...> spring tag not working.. i think this is about spring problem .. is their any solution in spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly because reference issues. Please check following, preferably using Firebug or developer tools in browser

1. jQuery UI with compatible version of jQuery is properly referenced
2. jQuery UI CSS is referenced properly
3. jQuery UI js is referenced

[image: CDN]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: all the above 3 files also keep into my application, is it required to  give http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js or over local path is enough ?

Comment: local path is enough but make sure they are referenced properly. If you can see them in firebug. At times the local path is not properly defined which result missing reference silently

Comment: why some of the div tags are invisible at firebug? it means it is show light color, there is no action when we change these light color visible tags?

Comment: I didn't get you! One way to check whether the scripts were properly loaded is to see Console section. It throws exception if something is not found.

Comment: Otherwise first try removing your references and referring to three CDN source in order to make sure its local path problem.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are not loading the jquery.js.....u need jquery file to run the ui component..

load jquery.js befor jquery-ui.min.js

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You missed the jQuery UI CSS which is also required

Comment: that is loaded check the question third line ..:) :)

Comment: No this is not main jsp, this is sup jsp, i'm include that jquery-1.9.1.js in main jsp is it required to configure in sub jsp also?

Comment: do u get any error ?? like `$ is not defined` or anything check your console..  ??

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code

```
<form:input path="fromDate" cssClass="date-picker" />
```

Your code is acceptable,

```
<form:input type="text" path="fromDate" class="date-picker" />
```

because all of the Spring MVC form tag support dynamic attributes, like HTML5 `placeholder`.  Unless you are using older version of Spring.