# JSP not receving parameter from jquery datepicker

Tags: java, forms, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, jsp-tags

I have following code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<t:page>
    <jsp:attribute name="scripts">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
                });
            });
        </script>
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
        <h2 class="page-header">Edytuj etap</h2>
        <t:messages/>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <form:form action="edit" method="POST" role="form"
                          commandName="masterCheckpointForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form:input type="text" path="deadline" cssClass="form-control" id="datepicker"/>
                        <form:errors path="deadline" cssClass="label label-danger" element="span"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                        <a role="button" class="btn btn-default"
                         href="<c:url value="/editions/${currentEdition.id}/master_checkpoints" />">
                    </div>
                </form:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </jsp:body>
</t:page>
```

My problem is that even if I change the date using datepicker and post the form, the `deadline` is not changing on server side. If I change from jQuery to `<input type='date'>` it is working fine. What may cause the problems with jQuery and JSP?

Comment: how do you load jQuery?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826223/spring-form-tag-based-datepicker-in-jquery